# Java - Recursive solution for subset sum

Tags: java

I am told to write a recursive function that takes a start index, array of integers,and a target sum, your goal is to find whether a subset of of the array of integers adds up to the target sum.

The example I am given is groupSum(0, {2, 4, 8}, 10) should return true because 2 and 8 add up to the target, 10. All I've been able to do so far are the base cases.

```
public boolean groupSum(int start, int[] nums, int target) {
    if (nums.length == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if (start == nums.length - 1)
    {
        return nums[start] == target;
    }
    else
    {
        ?????
    }
}
```

I have no idea where I should go with the actual recursive call. Since I can't pass a collective sum between calls, I don't see how I can add a number in each recursive call until I reach the target. Also, like shown in the example, I have no idea how I could have my code realize when a number won't work and just skip it, like the example did with 4. I'm thinking along the lines of that I should subtract numbers one at a time from int target and then recursively call the method with a new starting point and the new value for target, but I have no idea how I could use that to see if there is a valid subset.

I would appreciate  any help that can help me understand how to do this problem so that I can finish it. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Checking if a set of 3, 2, and 1 can add up to 8. Start with the 3. You have two cases. You need to check whether the remaining set (2 and 1) can add up to 8 by themselves. You also need to check whether the remaining set can add up to 8 with the 3 included, IE whether the remaining set can add up to (8 - 3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you point out you can change the target rather than passing a collective sum. Once the target is zero you know that you've got a solution (by selecting no members of the remaining items).

So, in psueduo code:

```
hasMembersThatSumTo(list, total):
    if total == 0
        return true
    else if total < 0 or list is empty
        return false
    else
        int first = list.pop
        return hasMembersThatSumTo(list, total - first)
            or hasMembersThatSumTo(list, total)
```

The two cases in the 'or' statement are looking for this situation in which the current element is either in or not in the sum.

Comment: you should have described reason and explanation of _the current element is either in or not in the sum_

Answer (score 1):

This should work according to the given conditions.
Initially the value of `start = 0`

```
boolean subsetSum(int start, int[] nums, int target) {
     // target is the sum you want to find in the nums array
     if (target == 0) return true;
     if (start > nums.length-1 || nums.length == 0)
        return false;
     if (nums[start] > target) 
        return subsetSum(start+1, nums, target);
     return subsetSum(start+1, nums, target) || subsetSum(start+1, nums, target - nums[start]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version. See comments in the code for explanation.

```
public static boolean recursiveSumCheck(int target, int[] set) {
    //base case 1: if the set is only one element, check if element = target
    if (set.length == 1) {
        return (set[0] == target);
    }

    //base case 2: if the last item equals the target return true
    int lastItem = set[set.length - 1];
    if (lastItem == target) {
        return true;
    }

    //make a new set by removing the last item
    int[] newSet = new int[set.length - 1];
    for (int newSetIndex = 0; newSetIndex < newSet.length; newSetIndex++) {
        newSet[newSetIndex] = set[newSetIndex];
    }

    //recursive case: return true if the subset adds up to the target
    //                OR if the subset adds up to (target - removed number)
    return (recursiveSumCheck(target, newSet) || recursiveSumCheck(target - lastItem, newSet));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[dynamic programming](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-subset-sum-problem/). Maybe this will help you.